# Is AwsCrypto thread safe? Can we create the object of AWSCrypto once and use it for all the requests?

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-kms

Can we create the object of AwsCrypto just once and reuse it for all the request? Basically I want to create the `KMSClient` with `AwsCrypto` which can be used for encryption and decryption for multiple `CMKs`.

Below is the sample code:

```
public class KMSClient {

final private AwsCrypto awsCrypto;
final private Map<String, KmsMasterKeyProvider> kmsMasterKeyProviderMap;

public KMSClient(AwsCrypto awsCrypto){
    this.awsCrypto = awsCrypto;
    this.kmsMasterKeyProviderMap = new HashMap<>();
}

public byte[] encrypt(final byte[] data, final String customerManagedKeyId) {
    return awsCrypto.encryptData(getKmsMasterKeyProvider(customerManagedKeyId), data).getResult();
}

public byte[] decrypt(final byte[] data, final String customerManagedKeyId) {
    return awsCrypto.decryptData(getKmsMasterKeyProvider(customerManagedKeyId), data).getResult();
}

private KmsMasterKeyProvider getKmsMasterKeyProvider(final String customerManagedKeyId){
    return kmsMasterKeyProviderMap.computeIfAbsent(customerManagedKeyId,
        k -> KmsMasterKeyProvider.builder().withKeysForEncryption(k).build());
}
```

Comment: The title could be more descriptive…

Answer (score 2):

AwsCrypto is thread safe except for setEncryptionAlgorithm and setEncryptionFrameSize. Those two methods are safe to call from multiple threads **as long as** every thread using that object is on board with changing the state. If one thread makes a change without others being ready for it, there will be trouble.